# Passing a thread object to service

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my activity I start a thread which works a long time. In order to stop the thread at application termination (when the user removes it from the recent app list), I want to call `thread.interrupt()`
in a service inside `void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)`. But I have no access to my thread object in my activity.

So my question is: How can I pass the thread to my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Threads don't implement serializable or Parcelable.  And passing a thread between a Service and Activity sounds like a horrible code smell.  Just create it in the Service.

Also-  remove it from the task bar?  What task bar?  There is no task bar in android, unless you have some odd UI running.

Comment: Thank you, I ment the recent task list.